# AWS Config Advanced Query SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use AWS Config Advanced Query to generate a report against a specific rule I have created.

```
SELECT
  configuration.targetResourceId,
  configuration.targetResourceType,
  configuration.complianceType,
  configuration.configRuleList
WHERE
  configuration.configRuleList.configRuleName = 'aws_config-requiredtags-rule'
  AND configuration.complianceType = 'NON_COMPLIANT'
```

Results look similar to this:

```
[
0:{
"configRuleName":"aws_configrequiredtags-rule"
"configRuleArn":"arn:aws:config:us-east-2:123456789:config-rule/config-rule-dl6gsy"
"configRuleId":"config-rule-dl6gsy"
"complianceType":"COMPLIANT"
}
1:{
"configRuleName":"eaws_config-instanceinvpc-rule"
"configRuleArn":"arn:aws:config:us-east-2:123456789:config-rule/config-rule-dc4f1x"
"configRuleId":"config-rule-dc4f1x"
"complianceType":"NON-COMPLIANT"
}
```

While this query produces results, it separates my config rule and compliance type, so I am not only getting results where my config rule is ONLY Non-compliance for 'aws_config-requiredtags-rule' results.

I am pretty novice with SQL, but hope there is a way for me to specify that I only want to see Non-Compliant results against a specific rule.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the AWS Config Service - and a pretty big one IMO. When you filter on properties within arrays, those filters are treated like `OR` operations instead of `AND`. There doesn't seem to be a good way of performing meaningful queries for individual rules.

[From the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/querying-AWS-resources.html#query-limitations):

> When querying against multiple properties within an array of objects, matches are computed against all the array elements
>
> ...
>
> The first condition configuration.configRuleList.complianceType = 'non_compliant' is applied to ALL elements in R.configRuleList, because R has a rule (rule B) with complianceType = ‘non_compliant’, the condition is evaluated as true. The second condition configuration.configRuleList.configRuleName is applied to ALL elements in R.configRuleList, because R has a rule (rule A) with configRuleName = ‘A’, the condition is evaluated as true. As both conditions are true, R will be returned.